# Windows Server 2008 defrag log?

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, defragment

Is there a log file for Windows (Storage) Server 2008 built in defragmenter?  I can not find a log file, event ID, or anything that gives a reference to the status of the defragmenter.

From the built in Disk Defragmenter program, there is a "Last Run" date and time, but I dont know if that is the equivalent of completed.

Anyone know where to look?

Comment: dont know why someone just downvoted without a reason

Answer (score 0):

The command line version of `defrag` cannot [write to the event log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294743), so Microsoft suggests using scripts in combination with defrag's exit codes to create event log entries if log entries are desired. Also, for client machines a defrag is a scheduled task, so the last run time would be there, not sure about the server OSes though.

*Disclaimer:* I could have *guaranteed* it was a sched task in Vista/7, but checking my 7 machine it's not there, and I don't remember deleting it. Other sites [also say](http://www.drennanit.com/schedule-automatic-defrag/) it's a scheduled task in 7.

Comment: FYI Was not using the command line version, but the application the application on the tools menu from the drive properties.

Comment: i just looked at the article, it applies only to XP, but MS articles are smart and said it didnt apply to my OS (win 7) and to click a link...  So I will open it up on server 2k8 when I get into work, and see if it offers a link

Comment: @Keltari okay, whenever I've seen that link and clicked it I'm taken to some generic Windows support page, as opposed to a .NET documentation when I can choose the version of .NET I'm using, and be taken to the *same documentation but the specific .NET version I need*, but YMMV. Clicking the link for Windows 7 took me [here](http://support.microsoft.com/ph/14019), for example.

Comment: @Keltari also, I think the gui just calls the commandline anyway, but I could be wrong.